# How can a point of symmetry have a slope which isn't either $0$ or $±\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

I've got a bit of a doubt with a question I'm solving. It goes like this:

> For $a>0$, let $f:[-4a,4a] \to R$ be an even function such that $f(x) = f(4a - x) \hspace{2 mm}\forall x \in [2a, 4a]$ and 
>   $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(2a + h) - f(2a)}{h} = 4,$$
>   then
>   $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h-2a) - f(-2a)}{2h} = \hspace{2mm}?,$$

---

Here's my reasoning:

It's been given that the function is *even*, so it's obviously symmetric about the y-axis.
Another piece of information which has been give is that $f(x) = f(4a - x) \hspace{2 mm}\forall x\in [2a, 4a]$.
So it's gotta be symmetric about the line $x = 2a$ in the interval $ x\in[0,4a]$ too.

So the graph would look something like this:

[image]

Either that, or a cusp or a sharp corner would exist at $x = ±2a$.

But, in the question, it's given that $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(2a + h) - f(2a)}{h} = 4,$$

which means that the slope of the graph at $x = 2a$ is $4$.

How is this possible, if the only options are:

- as in the graph, a maxima (or a minima) exists, thus the slope is $0$.
- a sharp corner exists - which means that the derivative isn't defined at the point.
- a cusp exists - which means the slope is either $±\infty$!

So how is it possible that a portion of the graph be symmetric about a value, but still have a derivative which isn't either $0$ or $±\infty$? Or is it that the question is wrong itself?

Comment: Probably, at some point the assumption $h > 0$ got lost. If you include that, it all works out.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought about that, but then I remembered my professor said there was absolutely no error in the paper. Which is so ironic, really.

Comment: Well, professors make mistakes, like everybody else. Hopefully fewer than average, but you can't count on that.

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean the limit should be $h\to 0^+$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, whatever the method of choice is to say that $h$ approaches $0$ through positive values. (Choosing $h \to 0^-$ would of course work too.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, ahah. Anyway, even if I take $h\to0^+$, that would make $f'(-2a) = -4$, which would give me an answer of $-2$ which isn't in the options :O

Comment: @mikhailcazi $f'(\pm 2a)$ doesn't exist. But note that when you restrict $h$ to positive values, $\frac{f(h-2a)-f(-2a)}{2h}$ gives you half the _right_ hand side derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's true. But since it's symmetric, the slope at $x = -2a$ will be the the negative slope at $x = 2a$! Which would be -4. Dividing that by 2 we get -2, which isn't in the answers :/

Comment: @DanielFischer and even having $h\to0^+$ doesn't solve it out completely because then that'll disrupt the symmetry about $x=2a$. As I said, the only options are for (i) $0$ slope, (ii) a cusp (iii) a sharp corner. There simply can NOT exist anything else!

Comment: @mikhailcazi I agree with your list of options, and if we restrict to $h > 0$, we have (iii). But: $\frac{f(h-2a) - f(-2a)}{2h} = \frac{f(2a-h)-f(2a)}{2h} = \frac{f(2a+h)-f(2a)}{2h} \to +2$ by the evenness of $f$, and the symmetry about $2a$.

Comment: Aaah, yeah. Got it. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Daniel Fischer I now know what's the problem with the question. They should have specified that $h>0$. With that cleared, the graph of the function would have been something like:

[image]

The right hand derivative of $x=2a$ is 4, which implies that the left side derivative will be $-4$ (because of the symmetry). Again, symmetry implies the right hand derivative of $x = 2a$ will be the negative of the *left hand derivative $x = -2a$*, which is -(-4) = 4.

The answer = 
$$\frac{rhd}{2} = 2.$$

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(4a-x)=f(x)$, letting $x=2a+h$ gives $f(2a+h)=f(2a-h)$. Now, since the function is even, we have $f(-2a)=f(2a)$. Then we get $$\frac{{f\left( {2a + h} \right) - f\left( {2a} \right)}}{h} = \frac{{f\left( {2a - h} \right) - f\left( {2a} \right)}}{h}$$ so $$\begin{align}
 \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {2a + h} \right) - f\left( {2a} \right)}}{h} &=  - \mathop \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {2a - h} \right) - f\left( {2a} \right)}}{{ - h}} \\  f'\left( {2a} \right) &=  - f'\left( {2a} \right) \\ 
  f'\left( {2a} \right) &= 0 \end{align}$$

Thus **if** the derivative at $2a$ exists, we must have $f'(2a)=0$. This shows that $f'(2a)=4$ is impossible.

---

The "centered" derivative relies on the fact that **if** the derivative exists $$\displaylines{
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(a + h) - f\left( a \right)}}{h} = f'\left( a \right) \cr 
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( a \right) - f(a - h)}}{h} = f'\left( a \right) \cr} $$ But summing gives $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {a + h} \right) - f(a - h)}}{{2h}} = f'\left( a \right)$$

Comment: Yes, cusp-free, but the slope of $\sin^2 (x)$ at its symmetric points is $0$!

Comment: But the symmetry $f(x) = f(4a-x)$ for $2a \leqslant x \leqslant 4a$ says that $f(2a-h) = f(2a+h)$, hence if the limit $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2a+h) - f(2a)}{h}$ exists as a real number, it must be $0$.

Comment: @mikhailcazi I have changed the answer. As Ross said: good thinking! =)

Answer (score 2):

Good thinking.  If you use the centered expression of the derivative $$f'(2a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(2a+h)-f(2a-h)}{2h}$$ and the fact that $4a-(2a-h)=2a+h$ the numerator is zero.

Comment: umm, centered expression = ?

Comment: @mikhailcazi See my answer to obtain Ross' formula.

Comment: The usual derivative formula has one end of the secant at the point in question and one end a distance $h$ away.  You can also take points centered on the point where you want the derivative, as I have done.  Mathematically, you must get the same limit.  The centered expression has some numeric advantages, and in this case makes clear that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function. For $0< h\leq 2a$ one has
$${f(2a+h)-f(2a)\over h}={f(2a-h)-f(2a)\over h}=-\ {f\bigl(2a+(-h)\bigr)-f(2a)\over(-h)}\ .$$
Letting $h\to{0+}\>$ implies  $4=-4$.

Comment: But there is symmetry about $x = 2a$ which means if $f'(2a^+)$ is $4$, $f'(2a^-)$ has to be $-4$.

Comment: Of course, that removes any differentiability at the point - but it doesn't matter :D It was never mentioned that it is differentiable throughout.